# Terraform how to fix attribute "route": set of object required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this `terraform` module `route_table.tf` I need to use. It looks like below:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "aws_route_table" {

  # route {
  #   cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  #   gateway_id = var.GATEWAY_ID
  # }

  route = var.ROUTE

  tags = var.ROUTE_TABLE_TAGS

  vpc_id = var.VPC_ID
}
```

and I have defined the variable `ROUTE` as below in the `inputs.tf`:

```
variable "ROUTE" {
  type = object({ cidr_block=string, gateway_id=string })
}
```

And I am passing those values in the `main.tf` as below:

```
module "route_tables_public" {
  source = "./modules/route_tables"

  ROUTE =    {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = var.GATEWAY_ID
  }

  ROUTE_TABLE_TAGS = { "Name" : "mlb-rt-public" , "Project" : "mlb"}
  VPC_ID           = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Inappropriate value for attribute "route": set of object required.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var.ROUTE` is a single object, but it should be **list of objects**. So you can try:

```
variable "ROUTE" {
  type = list(object({ cidr_block=string, gateway_id=string }))
}
```

and then

```
module "route_tables_public" {
  source = "./modules/route_tables"

  ROUTE =    [{
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = var.GATEWAY_ID
  }]

  ROUTE_TABLE_TAGS = { "Name" : "mlb-rt-public" , "Project" : "mlb"}
  VPC_ID           = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your `aws_route_table` should be:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "aws_route_table" {

 dynamic "route" {
 
   for_each = var.ROUTE
   
   content {
      cidr_block = route.value.cidr_block
      gateway_id = route.value.gateway_id
    }
  }

  tags = var.ROUTE_TABLE_TAGS

  vpc_id = var.VPC_ID
}
```

Comment: Not working, can you tell me how my resource going to look like? Is it same as the one I have mentoned

Comment: Gives the error `Inappropriate value for attribute "route": incorrect set element type:`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against directly assigning variable values to complex resource type arguments like this, because if the schema of the `route` argument were to grow to include additional attributes in the future then your module would fail validation.

Instead, better to let the variable's type be independent of the `route` block schema and translate explicitly between them, which should then allow this to work as long as a new version of the provider doesn't introduce a new *required* argument for that block.

```
variable "route" {
  type = object({
    cidr_block = string
    gateway_id = string
  })
}

resource "aws_route_table" "aws_route_table" {
  # ...

  route {
    cidr_block = var.route.cidr_block
    gateway_id = var.route.gateway_id
  }
}
```

This can work because it's constructing a new object that conforms to the `route` block schema using two attributes of your object, whereas your example fails because you tried to assign the input object *directly* to that argument, which would require that you match the target type exactly.

Please note that naming variables all in uppercase is not idiomatic Terraform style, so in the above example I renamed the variable to be `route` instead. `ROUTE` would also work, but would be an unusual way to name a Terraform variable.